# $X\sim \operatorname{Uni}[-1, 1]$, $y = x^2$. Find $Cov(x, y)$

Tags: probability, expectation

$X\sim Uni[-1, 1]$, $y = x^2$. Find $Cov(x, y)$

$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{R-L} = \frac{1}{2}$

$Cov(x, y) = E(XY)$  <- Would this formula be right?

The solution does it like this: $Cov(x, y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) = E(XY)$.

Is it $E(XY)$ or $E(XY) - E(X)E(Y)$?

No clue how to work with $Y$, by definition this would be

$$E(XY) = \int_{-1}^{1}xy \frac{1}{2}dx = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{2}x^3dx = \left[ \frac{x^4}{8}\right]_{-1}^{1} = 0$$

Comment: Your notation ins very very sloppy. Where you wrote $y=x^2$ it is impossible not to suspect you meant something like $Y=X^2.$ Then you write $\operatorname{Cov}(x,y) = \operatorname E(XY)$ with lower-case $x,y$ on the left and capital $X,Y$ on the right. Then you use lower-case $x,y$ as arguments to the density functions after using them also as names of random variables. You will be confused until you get clear about these things. One cannot even understand something like $\Pr(X\le x)$ if one doesn't know any difference between $X$ and $x. \qquad$

Comment: Suggestion (in addition to @MichaelHardy's excellent points above): **check your definitions, young padawan!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)= \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)$

However here, $\mathsf E(X) =0$, so that reduces to $\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf E(XY)$.

$$\mathsf {E}(X)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x}2\mathrm d x=0$$

And yes, $\mathsf E(XY)=\mathsf E(X^3)$ which equals $0$ also.

$$\therefore~~\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{x^3}2\mathrm d x=0$$

---

---

PS: If you actually did need to find it, use $\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(X^2)$ and the above method.   It equals $\tfrac 13$ .